# Bootstrap responsive tab - accordion, panel won't close when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a jQuery plugin to make some bootstrap tabs responsive by converting the tabs to an accordion on sm & xs resolutions. It is working fine, however it does not function like a normal bootstrap accordion - as I want to be able to close an accordion panel by clicking on the panel-title, however this does not work with this plugin. How can I make it to where the accordion panel will collapse if a user clicks on the panel-title of the active panel? I know in an actual bootstrap accordion, this would be accomplished by adding the data-toggle="collapse", but I am not very familiar with js, so I am unsure how to edit the plugin js to accomplish this. You can see a working jsfiddle example using the link below.

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs responsive-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a href="#home1">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#profile1">Profile</a></li>
  <li><a href="#Tab3">Tab3</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="home1">
    <p>1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="tab-pane" id="profile1">
    <p>2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="tab-pane" id="Tab3">
    <p>2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.responsive-tabs').responsiveTabs({
  accordionOn: ['xs', 'sm'] // xs, sm, md, lg
});
```

jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/r40qvmww/16/

Comment: Please post the code you've written.

Comment: This might be by design - that the accordion functions like tabs because that's what its representing. You always have to have 1 tab open, so you also always have 1 accordion panel open in the responsive view. Part of the reason that it doesn't function exactly like the accordion is because it use the tab markup not the accordion markup. But this doesn't mean you can't do it lol